# ExtJS 4 can't listen to events from component inside tab

Tags: events, extjs

I defined a tabpanel with several tabs, in one of them I have a panel with a grid and something else. I defined a controller to get the events from the grid. While I can get the event from the panel it's impossible to get events from the grid.

Here's the viewport is here:

```
Ext.define('test.MyViewport', {
  extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

  layout: 'fit',

  items: {
      xtype: 'tabpanel',
      items: [{
          title: 'Tab 1',
          html: 'something'
      },{
          title: 'Tab 2',
          xtype: 'mypanel'
      },{
          title: 'Tab 3',
          html: 'something else 2'
      }]
  }
```

Here's the panel:

```
Ext.define('test.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    alias: 'widget.mypanel',

    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        border: 1
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'mygrid',
        width: 300
    },{
        xtype: 'component',
        html: 'Hello There'
    }]
});
```

And here's the controller:

```
Ext.define('test.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'mypanel': { show: function(){console.log( "Show Panel" );} },
            'mygrid': { show: function(){console.log( "Show Grid" );} }
        });  
    }
});
```

The complete code can be tested in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zGVXK/).

I tried many different selectors:

```
mypanel mygrid
#my-grid-id  (setting itemId on the grid item in the panel)
mypanel #my-grid-id
...
```

With no success. I've spent two days on this and don't have a clue on how to solve it. Should I start a different controller for that specific view? If so where should I put it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: +1 I love working example in fiddles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It is just the way the layout woks...

The card layout of your demo will hide the 'test.MyPanel' and so call `show()` each time the tab gets activated but that is (luckily) not done for all of the 'test.MyPanel' component child's.

Why? Because it is not necessary.

They are not directly hidden themself, only through their owner Container and therefor show never get called and so the event never get fired. It is just the way the layout works. So if you place a grid as direct child into a tab the show event get fired as well. See this forked **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/5REAQ/)**

Comment: Thanky very much that's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The selector is OK, the problem is that the `show` event of the grid is never fired. The tab layout does call the `show()` method of its direct children, which fires the `show` event, but most layouts do not.

You can confirm that the `show` event of the grid is never fired by adding a listener directly in your grid definition:

```
{
    xtype: 'mygrid',
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    listeners: {
        // won't happen
        show: function() { alert('Grid show event') }
    }
}
```

And you can confirm that your control method has correctly grabbed the reference to the grid by listening for other events:

```
    this.control({
        'mypanel': { show: function(){console.log( "Show Panel" );} },
        // will happen when you click on the grid's body
        'mygrid': { containerclick: function(){console.log( "Grid clicked" );} }
    });
```